# Time Series Regression and Correlated Residuals Dataset

Tags: data-request, time-series

Can somebody please introduce me to a time series regression **dataset** that has many variables and data point?

In a nutshell, I have a time series regression with auto correlated residuals.
Note that I can artificially simulate a dataset. Then I need a real dataset. For sure there are many datasets that this model works well on them but I cannot find anything at the mean time.I  also have checked this page [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples) but no progress. I would be thankful if somebody introduce me a dataset and probably associate paper.